# Run ASP.Net MVC application in IIS 7 that built target framework as .Net 4.5.2

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, iis-8

I have an ASP.Net MVC application that sets Target Framework as `.Net Framework 4.5.2`

I have to deploy this application to 2 servers that one is `Microsoft Windows server 2008 R2 Enterprise` (This one has `IIS 7`) and other one is `Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter` (This one has `IIS 8`).

I deployed the application to above 2 servers.  MS Server 2012 is working fine and MS Server 2008 is giving an error.

**Here are things that I have done so far.**

I have installed `.Net 4.5.2 Framework` to `MS Server 2008`.

It installed successfully. But I checked the file location.

Here is the screen grab.

(Please check the folder location also)

[image]

Then I compare with `MS Server 2012`. Here is the screen grab.
(Please check the folder location)
Inside the .NETframeworks folder it has folder called `v4.0`

[image]

Here are the application pools in `IIS 7`.

[image]

Here is the application pool in `IIS 8`.

[image]

Can someone please advise me to overcome this situation.

**Update**

```
Event Viwer -> Windows Logs -> Applications
```

shows this error.

```
PlatformNotSupportedException 
   This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode. at 
System.Web.HttpResponse.get_Headers() at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallHeaders.AspNetResponseHeaders..ctor(HttpResponseBase response) at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinCallContext.CreateEnvironment() at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.GetInitialEnvironment(HttpApplication application) at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.PrepareInitialContext(HttpApplication application) at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.BeginEvent(Object sender, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extradata) at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: What's error message you get on MS Server 2008?

Comment: When I enter URL from browser it shows generic runtime error message

Comment: Did you check .NET framework 4.5 is installed with registry on 2008?

Comment: Can you please check the `Event Viewer -> Windows Logs -> Application` logs and tell us the exact error, what you receiving when are you accessing it from the browser? For ex, it might be that one of the modules is not installed, like `url rewrite` or others

Comment: @Nico I checked in the registry. It is there.

Comment: @NoughT you must use the integrated mode app pool instead. try it and write me back

Comment: @VictorLeontyev Thank you very much for your tip. I have added the error.

Comment: Did you install the .NET Framework 4 before IIS was enabled?

Comment: In that case I really don't know about that because I got work with this server today

Comment: Change your application pool, that is used for the application, to integrated mode, then inform about result, please.

Comment: I was able to register .Net 4.5 with IIS 7 and then changed the application pool to integrated mode. Now it is working. Thank you all for your valuable thoughts.